# C# DataTable.Select() - How do I format the filter criteria to include null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

This doesn't work

```
DataTable myNewTable = myDataTable.Select("Name <> 'n/a'").CopyToDataTable();
```

`myDataTable` has a row named `Name`. I would like to select the rows from this table where Name is not equal to "n/a". It selects but still am missing the null values i need the null values too.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this

```
myDataTable.Select("[Name] is NULL OR [Name] <> 'n/a'" )
```

Edit:  Relevant sources:

- [DataTable.Select Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)
- [Expression filtering syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

**Try out Following:**

```
DataRow rows = DataTable.Select("[Name]<>'n/a'")
```

**For Null check in This:**

```
DataRow rows =  DataTable.Select("[Name] <> 'n/a' OR [Name] is NULL" )
```

Comment: This isn't going to include the rows where Name is null.

Comment: Your edit simply made this a duplicate of other answers that beat you to the correct answer. It serves no purpose, you should just delete this.

Comment: @user414076 may be you are correct, as others mentioned, i didnt mentioned it. But thanks. I again edited it.

Comment: May be 'DataRow rows =' will be 'DataRow[] rows ='

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var result = from r in myDataTable.AsEnumerable()  
            where r.Field<string>("Name") != "n/a" &&  
                  r.Field<string>("Name") != "" select r;  
DataTable dtResult = result.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: You don't need to filter out empty strings. The first part of the predicate will work for him, however.

Comment: @user414076, if user want to check string.empty?

Comment: If the user *wants* to do that, then yes, it would be included. But this user made no mention of it. He wants only to filter out "n/a" with his query. His problem is that the code was *also* filtering out nulls. He didn't want that, so presumably he doesn't want empty strings filtered out, either. Make sense?

Answer (score 3):

The way to check for null is to check for it:

```
DataRow[] myResultSet = myDataTable.Select("[COLUMN NAME] is null");
```

You can use `and` and `or` in the `Select` statement.

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate the correct solution, it only shows part of it.